# Random Characters added to String

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to add a random set of numbers to the end of a string. I'm still learning the basics of VBS but this has really tricked me and I can't seem to find anything online.

I've tried:

```
string2 = "hello" + (Rnd() * Len(VALID_TEXT)) + 1
```

And:

```
x = rnd*10
string2 = "hello" + x
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: VBScript is not VB.NET.  The usage guidance on the tags tells you so.  The snippet is nonsense and wont compile in either one

Comment: Must have pressed enter on it. Sorry! I removed it.

Comment: What is `VALID_TEXT` and what is your expected output?

Comment: What isn't working?  You haven't specified the details of any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All random number generators rely on an underlying algorithm, usually fed by what’s called a seed number. You can use the Randomize statement to create a new seed number to ensure your random numbers don’t follow a predictable pattern.

To get the random numbers, using `rnd` alone is not sufficient as you will keep on getting the same random number again and again. You have to use `randomize` to achieve the task as shown below:

```
Dim strTest:strTest = "Hello"
Dim intNoOfDigitsToAppend:intNoOfDigitsToAppend = 5
Randomize
Msgbox "String before appending: " & strTest
strTest = fn_appendRandomNumbers(strTest,intNoOfDigitsToAppend)
Msgbox "String before appending: " & strTest

function fn_appendRandomNumbers(strToAppend,intNoOfRandomDigits)
    Dim i
    for i=1 to intNoOfRandomDigits
        strToAppend= strToAppend & int(rnd*10)           'rnd gives a random number between 0 and 1, something like 0.8765341. Then, we multiply it by 10 so that the number comes in the range of 0 to 9. In this case, it becomes 8.765341. After that, we use the int method to truncate the decimal part so that we are only left with the Integer part. In this case, 765341 is truncated and we are left with only the integer 8
    next
    fn_appendRandomNumbers = strToAppend
end function
```

**[Reference 1](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_rnd.asp)**

**[Reference 2](https://wellsr.com/vba/2017/excel/vba-random-number-with-rnd-and-randomize/)**

Answer (score 0):

`&` is the string concatenation character. `+` is an old compatability concat character and will error if you mix text and numbers. Use `+` for maths only.